# matrix multiplication performance

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Code goes as follows,

```
In [180]: rng = np.random.RandomState(123)

In [181]: A1 = rng.uniform(size=(10000,80))

In [182]: B1 = rng.uniform(size=(10000,30))

In [183]: A2 = rng.uniform(size=(80,10000))

In [184]: B2 = rng.uniform(size=(30,10000))

In [185]: %timeit np.dot(A1.T, B1)
10 loops, best of 3: 136 ms per loop

In [186]: %timeit np.dot(A2, B2.T)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.1 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit np.dot(A2, B1)
10 loops, best of 3: 56.3 ms per loop
```

I want to multiply `(A1, B1)` and `(A2, B2)` to form a `(80,30)` matrix, the difference here is that `A1` is defined as the transpose of `A2`, with `10000` rows in `A1` but `80` row in `A2`. Same for `B1,B2`.

The performance is quite different, I guess it's because the memory layout of `numpy.array` is more **cache-friendly** with **large columns** than with **large rows**, right? But how?

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, may I ask you to please post the time measurement for performing np.dot(A2, B1)?

Comment: Was your numpy compiled with any linear algebra library? Mine uses OpenBLAS, and I only see small differences between any of your versions, plus it runs almost 6x faster than your best timing...

Comment: @Jaime, not sure, but I guess it's about memory layout of `numpy.array` and CPU cache.

Comment: Try timing `A1.T.copy()` or a similar operation. On my system that runs in ~5ms. Matrix multiplication is an almost O(n^3) operation, so the O(n^2) operation of copying should not be too relevant for the overall final time. If your timings are similar, you can cut your worst timings to within 20% of your best result by some smart copying. A good library will do that for you, plus add multithreading and other goodies.

Comment: Based on the fact that (A2, B1) is slower than (A2, B2.T), and assuming that no optimization is implemented for np.dot() such as Strassen/Winograd, my theory is that it is much faster to access contiguous blocks of memory, assuming that rng.uniform(size=(80,10000)) results in contiguous memory to store 10000 elements for each row. Thus when performing matrix multiplication, when we scan the row one by one from the matrix on the left, and when we scan the column one by one from the matrix on the right, for (A2, B2.T), we are accessing contiguous bits of memory for each row/column scan.

Comment: @wookie919, yes, that's what I'm talking about, contiguous memory got cached.

Comment: @Jaime, ~5ms too, NICE idea to reduce the time cost, but increase memory overhead, right/

Answer (score 0):

MCM is an algorithm that computes the most efficient way to multiply a set of matrices, it's worth studying to learn more about matrix multiplication. In general matrix multiplication is not commutative and depending on the order you  can get radically different run times for computation.

[Standard Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication)

Comment: Matrix multiplication **IS** associative. And the OP is trying to multiply two matrices, so there is no ordering effect at work here...

Comment: @Jaime oops I meant commutative